# How can I find the type of a var/name in Actionscript3?

Tags: actionscript-3, types

Erm, that's it!...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function is called typeof().
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/operators.html#typeof

Comment: Will give you back 'object' for all but 5 predfined types.

Answer (score 25):

```
flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName(...)
```

You can pass any ActionScript value to this function to get a String containing its fully qualified class name.

Answer (score 8):

If you only need the most fundamental description of it's type, then you can use the `typeof` operator, like so:

```
var foo:String = "test";
trace( typeof foo );
// string
```

While this is convenient it has a drawback. That being it always gives the base type of the variable, for example:

```
var foo:Array = ["A","B","C","D"];
trace( typeof foo );
//object

var bar:int = 5;
trace( typeof bar );
//number

var hummer:Car = new Car();
trace( typeof hummer );
//Vehicle
```

Which are both technically right, but may not be what you're looking for.

If you want the more specific type (ie `Array`, `String` etc.) then you need to use the slightly more complicated `getQualifiedClassName()` function from the `flash.utils` package:

```
import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;

var foo:Array = ["A","B","C","D"];
trace( getQualifiedClassName( foo ) );
//Array

var bar:int = 5;
trace( getQualifiedClassName( bar ) );
//int

var hummer:Car = new Car();
trace( getQualifiedClassName( hummer ) );
//Car
```

[typeof documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#typeof)

[getQualifiedClassName() documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getQualifiedClassName%28%29)

Answer (score 5):

If memory serves me right, a method **flash.utils.describeType** hands you an xml document with all reflected typeinfo of an object/type.

Indeed: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29

Comment: Whoah, that's actually way too much info about types. I was hoping it also included actual values of properties. Oh well, good to know about anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The `is` operator is the up to date solution:

```
var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
trace(mySprite is Sprite);           // true
```

See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#is

Comment: That doesn't answer the question though, the question is "given a variable, how do I find out its type", not "given a variable how do I tell if it is a given type".

Comment: If the user knows the possible types of var, or wants to find out if the var is or is not a particular type then this solution will work.  Some of the other answers refer to deprecated functions (eg. typeof).